# awk ignores the record separator I set for the first record

Tags: linux, software-raid, awk

I am trying to change the record separator but awk does not use the record separator I set until the second record and beyond.

I get output like this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md4 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=e85beb4f:84b05929:786a31c9:93e269d4
ARRAY /dev/md6 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=4dbc659a:4d11f1be:6cbe4d26:c1372c53
ARRAY /dev/md5 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=7d34fc96:1fa6c3c5:b9932435:ad126815
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=862ae8d0:bd00b2fd:9e171b97:2937fc49
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=03bb1b77:42d474f4:608c5276:cc04d84c
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=6c14cddc:3ef74d2d:2f26fa3f:32cc274b
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=76e50525:9ae71e74:9697a0e6:6f77e132
```

I need output like this:

```
ARRAY=/dev/md4
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=e85beb4f:84b05929:786a31c9:93e269d4
ARRAY=/dev/md6
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=4dbc659a:4d11f1be:6cbe4d26:c1372c53
ARRAY=/dev/md5
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=7d34fc96:1fa6c3c5:b9932435:ad126815
ARRAY=/dev/md3
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=862ae8d0:bd00b2fd:9e171b97:2937fc49
ARRAY=/dev/md2
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=03bb1b77:42d474f4:608c5276:cc04d84c
ARRAY=/dev/md1
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=6c14cddc:3ef74d2d:2f26fa3f:32cc274b
ARRAY=/dev/md0
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=76e50525:9ae71e74:9697a0e6:6f77e132
```

When I try to format it awk does nothing with the first record but then correctly formats the rest of the recors.

Here is the command I am using with the output:

```
$ mdadm --misc -sD |sed 's/ /=/' |awk '{RS=" "}{print $0}'
ARRAY=/dev/md4 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=e85beb4f:84b05929:786a31c9:93e269d4
ARRAY=/dev/md6
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=4dbc659a:4d11f1be:6cbe4d26:c1372c53
ARRAY=/dev/md5
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=7d34fc96:1fa6c3c5:b9932435:ad126815
ARRAY=/dev/md3
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=862ae8d0:bd00b2fd:9e171b97:2937fc49
ARRAY=/dev/md2
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=03bb1b77:42d474f4:608c5276:cc04d84c
ARRAY=/dev/md1
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=6c14cddc:3ef74d2d:2f26fa3f:32cc274b
ARRAY=/dev/md0
level=raid1
num-devices=2
metadata=0.90
UUID=76e50525:9ae71e74:9697a0e6:6f77e132
```

And I cannot use this command as it leaves off the array and I need that `mdadm --misc -sDY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed` twice, the second time to replace spaces with newlines:

```
mdadm --misc -sD | sed 's/ /=/'| sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

or slightly optimized, only once but with two patterns:

```
mdadm --misc -sD | sed 's/ /=/;s/ /\n/g'
```

Comment: perfect thank you talk about a head slap moment as soon as i saw your answer I just groaned and shook my head  here is how I wrote before you edited your answer '$ mdadm --misc -sD |sed -e 's/ /=/' -e 's/ /\n/g'` I like your edit better Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would also prefer the sed-only solution given by @SvW, but to answer your question:

The `RS=" "` comes too late. It is set after the first line is read. You should call it in a BEGIN block, for example, to have an effect also for the first line:

`mdadm --misc -sD | sed 's/ /=/' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "}{print $0}'`

*Edit: Okay, @Thor was faster. :)*

Comment: I tried what I thought was this method before asking the question but had a typo in it which I did not see until I just went back through my history.  If you have two I's in BEGIN it does not work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not work because `RS` is set too late in the process. Set it before `awk` receives any input and it works correctly:

```
mdadm --misc -sD | sed 's/ /=/' | awk '{print $0}' RS=' '
```

Perhaps the following awk-only answer is also useful:

```
mdadm --misc -sD | awk '{$2=$1"="$2; $1=""} 1' OFS='\n'
```